# Baby steps to factorization of a large composite number via modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Given a huge composite number with unknown prime factors and a much smaller prime modulus *P*, is there a way (short of the Herculean task of factorization) to identify the residue classes mod(P) of the factors individually, or to determine whether the factors belong to the same residue class, and if so which?   Is the task easier for special choices of the modulus, and if so, how can one find them?

(If you could any of that, you could Chinese Remainder your way to the factors, but you might have to try an awful lot of combinations.  A guy can dream, can’t he?)

Comment: The short answer is: No. Even if there are only two factors, $N=pq$, knowning that $N\equiv 42\pmod {97}$ tells you only that $97\nmid N$ and once you know $p\bmod{97}$, you can find $q\bmod {97}$. But a priori, $p\bmod {97}$ can have all 96 possible values

Comment: If such a method would exist, I am convinced it would have been found. The chinese remainder theorem is so popular that surely many people thought about this approach.